# Copy data into v8::ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, v8, arraybuffer

I'm writing a Javascript interpreter in C++ using v8.
I need to pass a char buffer into an ArrayBuffer so that it gets garbage collected. Here is my code:

```
QByteArray data_buffer(file.readAll().data(), file.size());

v8::Handle<v8::ArrayBuffer> ab = v8::ArrayBuffer::New(args.GetIsolate(), data_buffer.size());
//insert code to copy data from data_buffer to ab
args.GetReturnValue().Set(ab);
```

If I use the constructor from the documentation in which I pass a pointer to the data, I'll have to deal with the memory myself and I don't want that.

I want to avoid allocating memory and let v8 do it's own memory management.
Couldn't find a way using Set() or any other function.

Any suggestions on how to copy data to the arraybuffer? Or how can I use the 2 parameters constructor to let v8 deal with the memory my data uses?

Documentation here: http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1ArrayBuffer.html Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way:

```
memcpy(ab->GetContents().Data(), data_buffer.data(), data_buffer.size());
```

Now I don't need to allocate memory and everything is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

http://v8.paulfryzel.com/docs/master/classv8_1_1_array_buffer.html#a28e84424cddbe397f3ee3d920189bc04

```
Local< ArrayBuffer > v8::ArrayBuffer::New   (   Isolate *   isolate, size_t     byte_length)
```

> Create a new ArrayBuffer. Allocate |byte_length| bytes. Allocated
>   memory will be owned by a created ArrayBuffer and will be deallocated
>   when it is garbage-collected, unless the object is externalized.